# How to create custom wrapper for devextreme column in datagrid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, wrapper, devextreme

I have an issue to wrap [Column](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Columns/Overview/) in my [DataGrid](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Getting_Started_with_DataGrid/). I want to create a custom component that returns a Column with proper formatting. For example, I need to create ColumnDate that adds my date formatting and I want to use it everywhere I need it so I don't need to copy the formatting string to every component.

```
const ColumnDate = (props) => {
  const dateFormat = "y-MM-dd";
  return <Column format={dateFormat} dataType="date" {...props} />;
};
```

I am using it in my DataGrid like that

```
<DataGrid>
  <ColumnDate dataField="date"/>
</DataGrid>
```

This won't work because this column is not visible in the grid. Using React Dev Tools there is a DataGrid->ColumnDate->Column and probably there should be DataGrid->Column instead (other columns directly below DataGrid are shown). Is there any way to make it work?

I create a sandbox to make it more clear what I want to achieve. You can find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/brave-hawking-19qu8x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're calling your functional component. You want it to behave as function and yet you're calling it as component.

[Igor Bykov](https://dev.to/igor_bykov) describes it perfectly in [this](https://dev.to/igor_bykov/react-calling-functional-components-as-functions-1d3l) article.

> When a functional component is used as `<Component />` it will have a lifecycle and can have a state.

To avoid that you need to call it as `{Component()}` .

As Igor said:

> If you have to declare a function that returns JSX inside a functional component (for instance, due to tightly coupled logic), directly calling it as `{Component()}` could be a better choice than using it as `<Component />`.

Hope it helps :)